# Calculating Contiguous String Kernel efficiently

Tags: algorithms, strings, kernel-functions

I am given two strings, $\overline{a},\overline{b}$ in a finite alphabet, $\Sigma$, and a positive integer $k$.   I want to compute the $k$-th order contiguous string kernel, which is defined to be the sum $$\sum_{s\in\Sigma^k}n_s(\overline{a})n_s(\overline{b})$$ where $n_s(x)$ is equal to the number of occurrences of $s$ as a substring of $x$.  I am trying to come up with an $O(k\ell_a\ell_b)$ algorithm for this, where $\ell_a,\ell_b$ are the lengths of $\overline{a},\overline{b}$, respectively.

I think the algorithm uses the fact that the substring must be present in both strings in order to actually affect the sum but I am unsure where to go from there in order to get such an algorithm. Any help or references to related sources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Where did you encounter this problem?  It sounds like you have read that this problem is solvable in $O(k \ell_a \ell_b)$ time.  Where did you read that?  Also, can you tell us what approaches you have considered, and where you got stuck?  Have you considered enumerating all substrings of length $k$ of $\overline{a}$?  How many can there be?  What's the fastest method you can think of computing $n_s(\overline{a})$, given $s,\overline{a}$? for computing $n_s(\overline{b})$?  We want to help you understand concepts, but just solving exercises for you might not help with that.

Comment: Thanks! So the approach I used to compute the whole kernel was using an indicator function, $f$, that is equal to $1$ iff the suffixes of the given strings are equal and then finding $\sum_i\sum_j f(a[i:i+k],b[j:j+k])$ where the indices go over all the elements in the strings. The problem with this approach, however, is that it is quadratic in the length of both strings. I am thus guessing I need a quite different approach but cannot really think of another method that won't rely on the size of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Thanks.  Please edit the question to show what you've tried, rather than posting a comment.  We want questions to stand on their own, so that readers don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Comments exist primarily to help you improve your question.  Also, please show what you think the running time of your approach is, and why (I think it already meets the stated running time you are looking for).  $O(k \ell_a \ell_b)$ is not what I'd call linear; I'd call it quadratic.  Thank you!